# Design REST API with different response parameters but same request

Tags: java, web-services, rest, http, jersey

I want to design rest API where there can be different response parameters for same request with different path variable.
Example :

```
URI : /mybook/{key}
```

Scenario 1 : `/mybook/page1`
response :

```
{
    a: "val1",
    b: "val2"
    c: "val3"
}
```

Scenarion 2 : `/mybook/page2`
response :

```
{
    d: "value4",
    e: "value5"
    f: "value6"
}
```

Scenarion 3 : `/mybook/page3`
response :

```
{
    g: "value7",
    h: "value8"
    i: "value9"
}
```

Is it possible to create it like above ? 
Should it be 3 separate APIs or Single API with all the request parameters ?

Comment: As so many URI- and API design related questions here on SO this is primarily opinion-based. There is no right or wrong and hence it depends soley on how you'd like to model it. Based on the samle JSON (or the actual question) this however has hardly anything to do with REST as the purpose of the API is probably different from the actual REST principles of decoupling a client from the API.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of pages as a resource and you have only one book, you would probably design the *API* as:

```
URI : /mybook/pages/{page-no}
```

and hence your scenarios would change to:

```
/mybook/pages/1
/mybook/pages/2
/mybook/pages/3
```

Otherwise, if `books` are your resource and pages are only views of a book, than you would probably design the *API* as:

```
URI : /books/{book-id}?page={page-no}
```

and hence your scenarios would change to:

```
/books/my?page=1
/books/my?page=2
/books/my?page=3
```

Comment: What if my page 1, 2, 3 have completely different response parameters ?

Comment: What do you mean with response parameters? Could you provide an example?

Comment: I think I got it. As long as the client knows what he might get and what not its ok. In your example he may get `a` or he may get `a` not. But if he knows about what he might get: `a` or `b` or ... `i` he can deal with it. And in your case perhaps: if you get `a` and you get `c` then I guarantee you get `b` as well. This would be a contract a client might deal with.

Comment: I came looking for whether or not all API responses for posts to a particular path MUST contain the same parameters whether they are relevant or not. Suppose you have a show url for vehicles that can handle cars, trucks or motorcycles and returns specifications of the vehicle. The question would be do I have to include a 'trunk space' parameter for a motorcycle as null or false (to preserve structure no matter the type) or can I leave it out entirely (expecting the user to know the type of vehicle they will be getting a response for)? Is this specified in the REST docs?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one API, wich is part of the question. I cant see a difference between scenarion 2 and secnarion 3. Are there any?

Comment: Responses parameters are different for the scenarios

Comment: I am sure you mean response values. You can do it all within a single RestController with Srping.

Comment: No, I mean response parameters . I have editted my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: What is a response parameter? Anyways it is possible to use it as a single API if you want.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible.

Technical it´s no difference if you do it in 3 separate APIs or one single API. I would separate them if there is a functional difference.

Greets

Comment: How is it possible to create different responses based upon pages

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is the usage of [pathParam](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html)

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/mybook")
public class UserRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("{bookID}")
    public Response getUserById(@PathParam("bookID") String id) {

       return Response.status(200).entity(prepareResponseForBookID(od)).build();

    }
    private Book prepareResponseForBookID(String id){
     //your code. you can return book entity or string json
 }

}
```